# SVG: Get clicked element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, svg, snap.svg

How to get the specific element inside SVG on which click was made?

```
    this.svgEl = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');        
    var s = Snap(this.svgEl);        
    var svgFromApi = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString("svg image from API", "image/svg+xml");
    s.clear();
    s.append(svgFromApi.documentElement);
    this.divElementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(this.svgEl); 

    this.svgElement.onclick = ()=> {               
           //Need to get on which element inside SVG it was clicked.   
       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
this.svgEl.onclick = (event) => {               
   // event.target should contain the element that was clicked on
}
```

Comment: Is there some way to check what the type of event.target is? Like is it an image or text?

Comment: `event.target.nodeName`